# Android Support Design Tablayout (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm getting the below error when I added the new [Xamarin Android Support Design Lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/22.2.0-beta3) into my xamarin project and running the app gets me this error.

> 06-09 15:49:50.353 E/AndroidRuntime(21768): Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a
>   Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010433 a=-1} 06-09
>   15:49:50.353 E/AndroidRuntime(21768):     at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2071) 06-09
>   15:49:50.353 E/AndroidRuntime(21768):     at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 06-09
>   15:49:50.353 E/AndroidRuntime(21768):     at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3572) 06-09 15:49:50.353
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21768):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:470) 06-09 15:49:50.353
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21768):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:101) 06-09
>   15:49:50.353 E/AndroidRuntime(21768):     at
>   android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.(HorizontalScrollView.java:150)
>   06-09 15:49:50.353 E/AndroidRuntime(21768):   at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.(TabLayout.java:214)
>   06-09 15:49:50.353 E/AndroidRuntime(21768):   at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.(TabLayout.java:210)

This is the Layout code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It would be great if some one could share a sample project(ASAP) with the above requirement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the android:background property from the TabLayout and it should work fine.